# Android Studio doesn't give me device list

Tags: android, android-studio

I am stuck with an issue when I run my application in android studio it runs on my computer but not on my connected device. Actually, it never even asks me if I want to run it on my android device or an emulator, it just runs without asking ?

EDIT:

My issue evolved into a even more complex issue. I now find myself in the configuration menu with this error:

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ObnW.png)

Comment: Please don't ask me to google before I ask, the answer to my question is nowhere to be found, not on their website nor here.

Comment: Restart the android studio and try running the application again.

Comment: On the left of the play button, you should have something like app, click and select Edit configurations, then go to "Deployement target option"

Comment: Harshit Agrawal, I've tried restarting the studio but sadly my issue still persists.

Comment: Chol, I saw this hint somewhere before and the problem is that I can't find the "Deployment target option" anywhere.

Comment: Should be there in the tab general

Comment: try the Chol solution. Try edit configurations.

Comment: Run the command "adb devices" does it list your phone?

Comment: Does your device have debugging enabled?

Comment: @Elton_Setan Make sure the device is connected properly or usb debugging is on or make sure the device is connected as camera.

Comment: I've tried searching in "Edit Configurations" but I didn't find anything and I don't really know what you mean by "General tab" as I only have these tabs: http://prntscr.com/j0ab1y | File;Edit;View;Navigate;Code;Analyze;Refactor;Build;Run;Tools;VCS;Window;Help.

Comment: A.Edwar, Micer, I don't know where to execute that command and yes, USB debugging is enabled and I've tried connecting the phone in all three modes including charging mode.

Comment: I also think it's worth mentioning that I ran my app before even thinking about trying to run it on my phone. So the issue is probably with my current configuration which I honestly, have no idea how to properly change.

Comment: @Elton_Setan refer to this for edit configurations https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html

Comment: The adb can be found in the platform-tools folder in the sdk

Comment: Harshit Agrawal, I am in fact in that menu but I still don't see the option you are mentioning.

Comment: A.Edwar, when I am in the android-sdks/tools folder there's no ADB there, could that be the issue or did you mean something completely else?

Comment: the folder is "platform-tools" not "tools"

Comment: I can indeed see my device when I run the command: .\adb.exe devices.

Comment: Then at least every thing on your device and adb is correct, the problem is surely with the android studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to find the Deployment Target Options to select what you want
[image]

Comment: My configuration menu differs quite a bit. I don't know how to attach a screenshot so I will provide a link via third party site: http://prntscr.com/j0aghi .

Comment: In defaults, go to Android App, but don't know why Application one is opened for you

Comment: I finally got to what you meant! But I still can't run it on my devices because I didn't specify a module that I can't specify because it doesn't give my any options (http://prntscr.com/j0alzd). It might be worth mentioning that this project was imported from Eclipse as that might be the core of these issues.

Comment: Oh, yes right maybe it is due to the import from Eclipse, don't know how to help you to fix it... Did you use the android studio importation tool when creating the project?

Comment: Yes, I've actually tried this through multiple methods. My first method was exporting my project into gradle and then importing it into Android studio. But that method yielded even more errors as I don't know how to even use gradle properly. After that I tried copying my program folder and implemeting gradle into it and then importing it into android studio. This method worked but I actually ran into a similar issue where I couldn't specify a module. And for the current method I downloaded a 30gb plugin into eclipse that enabled me to make an android project and I exported that project to AN.

Comment: And in android Studio, New, Import project and select your Eclipse project folder. Does it work better?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I didn't export it from eclipse into android studio but rather opened the import tool on android studio and then selected the folder in eclipse workspace, so basically what you said.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that it can't be fixed unless I rewrite my whole code. The code I tried to import into android studio is a converted java project which doesn't have the important properties of a android project and therefore can't be run as an apk.

Since Chol did answer the original question I will mark his answer as the correct one. Thanks to everyone who at the very least tried to help me.

Comment: It is shame it cannot be converted to a "real" android project... Good luck for your project, if it is not too big, maybe worth it to rewrite (copy litle by litle) all code